# How to create an orthogonal triad of vectors as a single object in Adobe Illustrator CC 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, 3d, pathfinder

Here is what I have done: I create three arrows by using the line command and then the stroke panel to add an arrowhead. I then make two duplicates of the arrow by pressing Alt + Shift + Left Arrow. Then, I use Effect -> 3D -> Rotate to rotate my 2D arrows into a right handed triad. The arrowheads lie in certain planes. When I go to unite the objects using the Pathfinder panel, it says: "The filter produced no results. Please select two overlapping paths."

I just want one object, essentially three right edges of a cube with arrowheads at the end, that I can use the 3D rotate command on to have an all-around orthogonal triad of vectors in my drawings.

Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be a single object? Even single objects have subcomponents, why would it matter if yiu had more levels (group)?

Comment: It would be easier to rotate. I would have one rotation instead of three.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to use 3D rotate (or any other effect), there is no need for pathfinder.

You can use effects on groups, so select all your arrows and group (**Object → Group** or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) then apply your effect to the group.

If you do want your arrows to be one single object you can create a compound path. Select all of your arrows and select **Object → Compound Path → Make** or hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>.

The reason for the pathfinder message is that pathfinder doesn't work well with open paths and strokes. You can outline your strokes (**Object → Path → Outline Stroke**) and pathfinder should work, but then you won't be able to edit your strokes or arrow heads.

Comment: When I rotate the three arrows as a group, they all rotate about their center points. I want them to rotate about their intersection so that I don't have to translate the vectors after the rotation. I just want three edges of a box that I can rotate, essentially.

Comment: Each object will rotate about its own center if you select multiple objects as it applies the effect separately to each object, if you apply the effect to a group it rotates about the common center as if it was one object. Make sure you have a group and only the group selected when you apply the effect.